# My site is receiving DNS errors on Google Webmaster Tools, how can I solve this?

Tags: google-search-console, dns, subdomain, error

I have several irregular DNS errors on a subdomain of my site.

[image: DNS]

On all my other subdomains, I have no issues (they have the same configuration)
Just `http://en-directo.frequence-radio.com` suffers this issue.
My hoster (OVH) is telling me they don't have any problem on their side.

What do you think I can do to solve this?

**Update:**

The test with the domain is OK (`frequence-radio.com`) on DNSsy.
The test with the subdomain has some issues, but no more than my other subdomains. I copy/pasted below all the failures from the test:

> Nameservers match (parent):   Some nameservers returned by the parent nameserver are not returned by your nameservers. The following
>   differences were found:   tllmxzfpqply.frequence-radio.com* (no idea
>   what is this last line)
>
> All nameservers responded:    Some of your nameservers did not respond. The following did not respond:   tllmxzfpqply.frequence-radio.com*
>
> All of your nameservers match:    Your nameservers returned different nameserver records.   At your nameservers I found: At parent
>   nameserver I found:    tllmxzfpqply.frequence-radio.com*
>
> All of your nameservers match:    Your nameservers returned different nameserver records.   At your nameservers I found: At parent
>   nameserver I found:    tllmxzfpqply.frequence-radio.com*
>
> SOA record:   None of your nameservers returned an SOA record for your domain. This is very bad. Skipping SOA tests.*

Comment: check your dns config on www.dnssy.com

Comment: Please use the account you posted this with to edit or add any answers to your question.

Comment: Your domain `en-directo.frequence-radio.com` does not pass DNS tests at all, see https://zonemaster.net/test/ce059a07120aedd5 for example. There are no NS records.